# Java Constructor to take an array?

Tags: java, constructor

I have created a default constructor which creates an empty "hand".

```
  public Hand() {
    hand = new ArrayList();
  }
```

Whats the most efficient way to have a second constructor take an Array of cards, then add them a hand?

Comment: *Most efficient* will be to store the same reference if the given array - but there are a LOT
 of draw backs in it.

Comment: In all games I know a hand does not contain many cards. Worrying about the most efficient way of doing this sound like premature optimization. I'd prefer the most clear/flexible way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would have one constructor to do both.

```
public Hand(Card... cards) {
    hand = Arrays.asList(cards);
}
```

Or an ArrayList copy as Rohit Jain suggests.

Comment: Note: `Arrays.asList` gives a fixed size `ArrayList`. of type: - `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`

Comment: But then he cannot add any cards to hand later, and the fact that he has a no-args constructor suggests that he would want to, doesn't it?

Comment: @RohitJain: It should be fine - there is no reason why `hand` won't be a `List`.

Comment: @amit.. Actaully, problem is not with the type of `hand`. Problem is that, it is `unmodifiable list`. That's why I used a constructor in my version.

Comment: It's hard to know what the requirements are but this is the simplest.  You might copy-on-write the `hand` or want to make it mutable with a copy.

Comment: @RohitJain: There are a lot of drawbacks in it. but it is *more efficient* - which is what is being asked here.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this: -

```
public Hand(String[] hands) {
    hand = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(hands));
}
```

---

Or, you can iterate over your string array, and add individual elements to your `ArrayList`.

```
public Hand(String[] hands) {
    hand = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String elem: hands) 
         hand.add(elem);
}
```

P.S: - Always declare a `Generic Type` List.

Comment: This is definetly not *most efficient*

Comment: @amit.. Do you suggest iterating over the array and adding it to the `ArrayList`?

Comment: No, I suggest a plain and stupid reference store or Arrays.asList alone (which fits perfectly assuming `hand` is a `List`, as it should be)

Comment: @amit.. Well, you know that `Arrays.asList` returns a fixed size list right? So, if you just assign it, you won't be able to modify it.

Comment: @amit: If you think this is a good solution, why do you advice against it in your comment below the question?

Comment: @arne.b I didn't think it (reference store/asList()) is a good solution, I think it is *most efficient* - which is what the questions is asking.

Comment: @amit.. Lol. you again wrote `it is most efficient`. May be by mistake I think. But you see, even your hands want you to write that. ;)

Comment: @amit.. Please don't blindly follow what question is saying. If I had just posted the the `Arrays.asList` version, then OP would have come with a new question in few hours asking how to modify the created list. Which will result in this answer only. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's another option, `Collections.addAll`:

```
public Hand(Card[] cards) {
    hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
    Collections.addAll(hand, cards);
}
```

According to the documentation:

> Adds all of the specified elements to the specified collection.
>   Elements to be added may be specified individually or as an array. The
>   behavior of this convenience method is identical to that of
>   c.addAll(Arrays.asList(elements)), but this method is likely to run
>   significantly faster under most implementations.